# can't display data same with marker in infowindow google maps api (v3)

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, amcharts

I want to display amcharts in the infowindow google maps, But my charts can't looping data in infowindow.
If i click marker 1 data ratio can't show and click marker 2 data ratio marker 1 can show, but marker 2 can't show.

[Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/henrygunawan/pen/ZXRLjV/)`My Code`

How to display data infowindow same with marker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AmChart's `makeChart` method requires that the ID specified in the first parameter exists in the DOM or else it won't work. You're calling initAmCharts before the info window is even attached to the DOM, so you need to add a `domready` listener to the infowindow and call `makeChart` there. You also want to attach a `close` listener to clear out the chart instances in order to conserve resources, however you need to clone your chart data during the `domready` event so that clear doesn't outright delete them.

Here's the code that adds and clears the chart while preserving your data. I removed the shift calls as they seemed redundant and also broke the chart when re-opening the infowindow:

```
      var chartLine;
      var chartWa;
      google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
        var line_data_copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item.line_data_chart));
        var wa_data_copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item.wa_data_chart));
         chartLine = initAmChart("divChartLine", colors_line, line_data_copy);
         chartWa = initAmChart("divChartWa", colors_wa, wa_data_copy);

          chartLine.allLabels[0].text = item.line_ratio+"%";
          chartLine.validateData();       

          chartWa.allLabels[0].text = item.wa_ratio+"%";
          chartWa.validateData();       
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'close', function() {
        chartLine.clear();
        chartWa.clear();
      })
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/1a09e9e026ed47957ee9484e7b8cf258/?editors=0010)

Comment: @xorsparkI had tried, but how to close automatic maps if domready ub event click? 
I tried to remove this 
              infowindow.setContent(infowindowChart);
              infowindow.open(marker.getMap(),marker);
          });//end_marker_listener        
        
          google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'close', function() {
            chartLine.clear();
            chartWa.clear();
          })

and replace with this
 infowindow.close();      
 infowindow.setContent(infowindowChart);
 infowindow.open(marker.getMap(),marker);
 });

but not working

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask. Can you post a codepen that better explains the problem?